# Does there exist any linear time example for quick hull algorithm?

Tags: convex-hull

Suppose, the convex hull is a triangle and all the nonextreme points are interior to the triangle then is it possible that quick hull runs in linear time?

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at the [wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Convex_hull_algorithms) page. What you are referring to is an output sensitive convex hull algorithm. Small number of hull points result in near linear time algorithms. Same with Akl–Toussaint heuristic.